# Expectation of a composite function.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

[image]

My thoughts on the solution:

I noticed that the ln function "stretches" the intervals of X like: (-1; 0) to (-inf; 0), and (0; 1) to (0; ln2).

Intuitively, it becomes clear that due to the long interval of negative values of ln(1+x), the expectation will also be negative. But I haven't figured out how to strictly prove it.

In general, it is probably worth considering the integral: ∫1−1ln(x+1)f(x)dx, where f(x) is probability density function.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? How did you start and where precisely did you get stuck? Edit those details into the question as well. Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) to get helpful answers and avoid getting your questions closed.

Comment: @Martund, thanks for your attention.

I noticed that the ln function "stretches" the intervals of X like: (-1; 0) to (-inf; 0), and (0; 1) to (0; ln2).

Intuitively, it becomes clear that due to the long interval of negative values of ln(1+x), the expectation will also be negative. But I haven't figured out how to strictly prove it.

In general, it is probably worth considering the integral:

$\int_{-1}^{1} ln(x+1) f(x) dx$, where f(x) is probability density function.

Comment: It would be good if you edit that into the question, anxie. There are people who don't read comments before voting to close a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\ln(1+X)<X$ for all $X\ne0$ and equality holds for $X=0$. Hence $Y\le X$, so $EY\le EX$ (since expectation of non-negative random variable $X-Y$ is non-negative). Also, since expectation of a non-negative random variable is zero iff that random variable is zero with probability $1$, so $EY=0$ if an only if $\ln(1+X)=X$ with probability $1$, which happens if and only if $X$ is degenerate at zero. $EY$ is negative otherwise.

My method of defining sign of the expectation is applicable for every function $f(X)$ such that $f(X)\le X$ for all $X\in (-1,1)$ and the inequality is strict except for $X=0$, and similarly also applicable for functions such that $f(X)\ge X$ in this interval and inequality is strict except for $X=0$.

Comment: @ClementC., Any convex/concave function on that interval satisfies the conditions I am using.

Comment: Thank you so much, Martund. The solution is simple and clear.

@ClementC., thanks to you, I learned about the elegant Jensen inequality and an equally elegant solution to this problem. Thank you very much too!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** based on what you know,
$$
f(\mathbb{E}[X]) = \ln(1+\mathbb{E}[X])=\ln 1 = 0
$$
and you are trying to say something about the sign of $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$, which by the above is equivalent to comparing $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ and $f(\mathbb{E}[X])$. Is there some inequality between $f(\mathbb{E}[X])$ and $\mathbb{E}[f(X)]$ you can think of using? What property of $f$ does it rely on?

**Further hint:** (click to reveal)

> Use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). Here, the properties you are using are $f(0)=0$, and concavity of $f$.

Comment: Basically, this type of analysis generalises to any concave (or convex, for the opposite conclusion) function with $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Note that the condition is incomparable to [the one obtained by Martund](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4124189/75808): there exist functions satisfying the convex/concave assumption on $[-1,1]$ which don't satisfy the assumptions from that answer (e.g., $f(x)=\ln(1+x^2)$), and vice-versa (e.g., $f(x)=x-1+\sin(x)$).